Valid Losf Configuration Directory
I am a beginner and not familiar with losf command. When I try to update slurm resource management on HPC cluster, I get an error showing:

valid LosF config directory was not detected.You must provide a valid
config path for your local cluster. This can be accomplished via one
of two methods: (1) Add your desired config path to the file ->
/opt/ohpc/admin/losf/config/config_dir (2) Set the LOSF_CONFIG_DIR
environment variable Example configuration files are availabe at ->
/opt/ohpc/admin/losf/config/config_example Note: for new systems, you
can also run "initconfig " to create a starting LosF
configuration template

Hereby, I modified the template (named as config_direct.template) available at /opt/ohpc/admin/losf/config. But again I get invalid losf directory error. One can see the losf config directory contents as:
https://github.com/hpcsi/losf/tree/devel/config
Every comments will be highly welcome

Is this about lsof or about LosF? Those seem like entirely different things.

Thanks for your comments @grawity_u1686 . This is losf. And I edited my question.
